# Memcached username and password using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to create username and password in the localhost connect with the memcached in laravel?

Comment: What is default username and password ?

Comment: You can use `MEMCACHED_USERNAME` and `MEMCACHED_PASSWORD` in your .env file to define memcache username password

Comment: in Laravel 5.4 Don't work Memcached because apache server saved memcache and laravel configuration is memcached so how to solve this Error.any one can know then help me please.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: FatalThrowableError in MemcachedConnector.php line 72:
Class 'Memcached' not found

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991908/php-5-4-laravel-class-memcached-not-found

Comment: but i used windows7 so how to install Libmemcached.or which place to copy hat library files.

Comment: Try this http://www.ubergizmo.com/how-to/install-memcached-windows/

Comment: Thank u - Nikhil Radadiya.

Comment: does it worked?

Comment: No.but thank you for try to solve my question.